# How to return None if the list has all values as None else return the truth value in the list in an efficient way

Tags: python, list, any

I have a mix of `True`, `False`, `None` in a list.
If I have all values as `None` in the list e.g `ListA=[None, None, None]` I will have to return `None`. Otherwise, If I have a mix of boolean values and `None` e.g. `ListA=[True, True, False, None]`. I need to return `True` for this list because it has one `True`.

Is there another efficient way to write this logic?

my code so far is:

```
any[listA] if list_A != None then None
```

Comment: something like `if all(x is None for x in listA): return None else: return any(listA)`

Comment: Although, this could be done in a single pass... but that's probably not worth it

Comment: `any[listA] if list_A != None then None` is not even valid Python. Also, `list_A != None` will _always be true_ because a list cannot be equal to None. Btw, what result is expected for `ListA = [None, False, False, None]` ?

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
my_list=[True,None, None, None]

if(any(my_list)):
    print("True")
else:
    print("None")
```

returns None if all items of my_list are None.if not returns True.

Using any() is by far the faster and effective alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
is_bool_or_none = lambda some_list: True if (True in [type(element) == bool for element in some_list]) else None
print(is_bool_or_none(your_list_here))
```